# Having an issue while doing Socket programming in C

Tags: c

> In this problem, client is sending server, two strings. And server is getting the values correctly, but the only problem is that after the loop breaks, n[0] and n[1] contains the same values, maybe the last value is overwritten on both indices. If I print n[0] and n[1] inside the loop right after storing values, it shows correct output.

```
const char * n[2];
    int i = 0;
    while(i<2)
    {
        valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024); 
        n[i] = buffer;
        printf(n[i]);
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }

    printf("After loop: \n\n");
    printf(n[0]);
    printf(n[1]);
```

> Sample output:

Hello

there

After loop:

therethere

Comment: Because there is only one `buffer` that stores the output. `n[0]` and `n[1]` are just pointers that point to the same buffer. `int i = 0; while (i < 2); { .... i++}` that's a `for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the `buffer` in the second iteration, consider using:

```
char buffer[2][1024];
while (i < 2)
{
    ssize_t size = read(new_socket, buffer[i], 1024);

    buffer[i][size] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", buffer[i]);
    i++;
}
printf("After loop: \n\n");
printf("%s\n", buffer[0]);
printf("%s\n", buffer[1]);
```

or using dynamic memory:

```
char *buffer[2];
while (i < 2)
{
    buffer[i] = malloc(1024);

    ssize_t size = read(new_socket, buffer[i], 1024);

    buffer[i][size] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", buffer[i]);
    i++;
}
printf("After loop: \n\n");
printf("%s\n", buffer[0]);
printf("%s\n", buffer[1]);
```

Notice that `read` can fail, always check the return:

```
ssize_t size = read(new_socket, buffer[i], 1024);

if (size == 0)
{
    // handle EOF 
}
else if (size == -1)
{
    // handle error
    perror("read");
    ...
}
```

Comment: It is also a good idea to check the return value for error or eof.

Comment: @DavidRanieri Hey, I'm facing another issue. I send two strings from client to server. But the output on server side is very inconsistent. Sometimes, it prints 2, then 1, then 2. It keeps fluctuating.

Comment: It's hard to say why this happens without seeing the code, I suggest you to open a new thread